# Create LTI system in Python from state matrices using scipy.signal.lti

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

[`scipy.signal.lti`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lti.html) claims to be able to accept four arrays, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, to define a system (in addition to other methods). However, it gives me an error, and I can find no examples illustrating this.

My code is simply:

```
A=np.array([[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[-2,1,-.02,.01],[1,-2,.01,-.02]])
B=np.array([[0],[0],[-1],[0]])
C=np.array([[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])
D=np.array([[0],[0]])
sys=scipy.signal.lti(A,B,C,D) #spelled out
```

with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py", line 317, in __init__
    self._update(N)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py", line 428, in _update
    self.C, self.D)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py", line 259, in ss2zpk
    return tf2zpk(*ss2tf(A, B, C, D, input=input))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py", line 315, in tf2zpk
    z = roots(b)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 203, in roots
    raise ValueError("Input must be a rank-1 array.")
ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.
```

What am I missing here? The matrix (array) sizes are correct.

Answer (score 7):

In the [state-space representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation), your input vector `D` has a size 2, which means that this control system has 2 output variables. I believe this is not supported by the current implementation of `scipy.signal.lti`.

For instance, the following input, with one output variable does work.

```
C=np.array([[0,0,1,0]])
D=np.array([[0]])
```

**Further details**. The issue is in that with your original input parameters,

```
num, den =  scipy.signal.ss2tf(A, B, C, D)
```

gives a 1D array for the denominator, but a 2D array for the numerator (i.e. several of them, since there are multiple output variables). But then `scipy.signal.tf2zpk(num, den)` expects both `num` and `den` to be just polynomials (i.e. 1D arrays). Hence, the failure to initialize the `lte` class.